# Checking a unique Player ID is valid with Name initials eclipse

Tags: java

I am having a problem with this code:

```
public void setID() {
   do {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);         
       pID = s.nextLine();
   } while(true);
}

boolean checkID(String plName) {
    String[] nameParts = this.pName.split(" ");

    char ini1 = nameParts[0].charAt(0);
    char ini2 = nameParts[1].charAt(0);
    char ini3 = nameParts[2].charAt(0);

    String ini = new     
    StringBuilder().append(ini1).append(ini2).append(ini3).toString();

    if(pID.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase(ini))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

I want to make a loop which check input a football player ID, with is code format is "xxx000", with "xxx" being his name initials, and "000" being number. Please help me finish this code, i think i did the first condition right, but i am stuck at the second. Thank you so much for your help!

By the way i have tried using the "isNumeric" found online example to tackle the second condition, but i can't seem to get it to work. It keep saying void type can't return to true or false. Can you clarify this for me?

I also think of a alternative way to do this, but im also struck at the second condition: to generate the "xxx" part using the player name, and format the "000" part for input, eliminate the need for a check method?

Comment: can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if it is number you can use regex

```
str.matches("^[0-9]{3}$");
```

In your code

```
if(pID.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase(ini) && pID.substring(3).matches("^[0-9]{3}$")){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false
};
```